# Check for null/empty in dictionary

Tags: c#, hash-map, null

I am doing the following about 10 times with other strings, so the code is duplicated.  How can I refactor this?

`queryWhere` is a `Dictionary<string,string>` that contains parameters that will be passed to a query.

```
string account = string.Empty;

if (queryWhere.ContainsKey("account") 
&& queryWhere["account"] != null 
&& !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryWhere["account"].ToString()))
    account = queryWhere["account"].ToString();

string customer = string.Empty;

if (queryWhere.ContainsKey("customer ") 
&& queryWhere["customer "] != null 
&& !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryWhere["customer "].ToString()))
    customer = queryWhere["customer "].ToString();


string balance = string.Empty;

if (queryWhere.ContainsKey("balance ") 
&& queryWhere["balance "] != null 
&& !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryWhere["balance "].ToString()))
    balance = queryWhere["balance"].ToString();
```

Comment: There's probably a lot to say about this, but the root of your problem may not be in this specific piece of your code. For example, why are you in a situation at all where you may have empty or null values that you don't consider valid? We could probably give a proper review if you included more of the code.

Comment: What is `queryWhere`?

Comment: @BCdotWEB - queryWhere is just a Dictionary<string,string> that contains  parameters that will be passed to a query.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each of these:

```
string account = string.Empty;

if (queryWhere.ContainsKey("account") 
   && queryWhere["account"] != null 
   && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryWhere["account"].ToString()))
{
    account = queryWhere["account"].ToString();
}
```

Should be reduced to:

```
string account;
if(!queryWhere.TryGetValue("account", out account))
{
   account = string.Empty; // if you need the string to be empty // default is null
}
```

[Dictionary.TryGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx)

But that logic can then be moved to a method:

```
private string GetValue(string key)
{
   string returnValue;
   if(!queryWhere.TryGetValue(key, out returnValue))
   {
      returnValue= string.Empty;
   }
   return returnValue;
}

string account = GetValue("account");
string customer = GetValue("customer");
```

---

I really don't see the point of your original code, BTW. For instance, the `.ToString()` is completely superfluous, since you're working with a `Dictionary<string,string>`. It is **always** going to return a `string`.

But why do you even check for `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`? You already know it isn't `null` from the previous line's check -- `queryWhere["account"] != null` -- so at worst it is empty which is your default value anyway!

Comment: I like this, much more concise, so if I don't care about the default, is all that is required is `queryWhere.TryGetValue(key, out returnValue)`

Comment: @xaisoft Indeed, plus it is the recommended way to handle such lookups if you're not certain the key is present in the dictionary. And it is [more efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382681/what-is-more-efficient-dictionary-trygetvalue-or-containskeyitem).

Answer (score 4):

Extract a method. Excuse the names here, but *naming is hard*.

```
public string GetIfValid(string fieldName)
{
    if (queryWhere.ContainsKey(fieldName) 
        && queryWhere[fieldName] != null 
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryWhere[fieldName].ToString())
        ) 
    {
        return queryWhere[fieldName].ToString();
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

---

```
string account = GetIfValid("account");
string customer = GetIfValid("customer");
string balance = GetIfValid("balance");
```